# edit two parts of text document python

Tags: python-3.x

Similar to my recent question asked:
I have a text file contain some data using this piece of code

```
def Add_score():
    with open("users.txt") as myFile:
        for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
            if name in line:
                line_found = num
                break
```

It finds the line that has a specific name. The line would look like this.

Name: whatever Username: whatever password: whatever score: 25 goes: 3

I need to be able to add number to score as well as goes

Change 3 to 4 and change 25 to 26

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
line = 'Name: Username: password: whatever score: 25 goes: 3'
print(line)
lineSplitted = line.split()
print(lineSplitted)
updatedLine = " ".join(lineSplitted[0:5] + [str(int(lineSplitted[5])+1)] + [lineSplitted[6]] + [str(int(lineSplitted[7])+1)])
print(updatedLine)
```

prints:

```
Name: Username: password: whatever score: 25 goes: 3
['Name:', 'Username:', 'password:', 'whatever', 'score:', '25', 'goes:', '3']
Name: Username: password: whatever score: 26 goes: 4
```